# How to avoid errors due to NaN, or other non numerical values in a column with rowcallback toExponential(2)

Tags: javascript, r, nan, dt

In a straight forward rowcallback to convert numbers, both positive and negative, to exponential, how would I adjust the javascript so that it skips rows in the column that contain a NaN value? 
Ideally I would also like to automate a solution to skip date columns when detected as the position of date columns might depend on the user's dataframe input in my R Shiny

The table options I have at the moment are these:

```
mtcars[1,5] <- NaN
mtcars[6,7] <- NaN

        Table_opts <- list(
          dom = 'frtipB',
          searching = F,
          pageLength = 50,
          searchHighlight = TRUE,
          colReorder = TRUE,
          fixedHeader = TRUE,
          buttons = c('copy', 'csv'),
          paging    = TRUE,
          columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all')),
          deferRender = TRUE,
          rowCallback = JS(
            "function(row, data) {",
            "for (i = 3; i < data.length; i++) {",
            "$('td:eq('+i+')', row).html(data[i].toExponential(2));",
            "}",
            "}")
        )
        DT::datatable(mtcars,  
        extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
        selection = c('single'),
        rownames = FALSE, 
        options = Table_opts
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

```
  rowCallback = JS(
    "function(row, data) {",
    "  for (i = 3; i < data.length; i++) {",
    "    var x = data[i];",
    "    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(x))){",
    "      $('td:eq('+i+')', row).html(x.toExponential(2));",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}")
```